# How can I avoid events firing during InitializeComponent?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a simple WPF page with a couple of RadioButtons, each RadioButton is registered with a `Checked` event handler so that when the selection is changed something can happen. By default I want to have one of these RadioButtons selected, so I have set the `IsChecked` property to `True` in the xaml. Something like this:

```
<RadioButton Checked="Radio_Checked" IsChecked="True">One</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Checked="Radio_Checked">Two</RadioButton>
```

The problem with this is that during `InitializeComponent` the `IsChecked` property causes the event to fire, this causes a null reference exception because my event handler attempt to use elements that have not been initialized yet.

Currently I have gotten around the issue by checking if the page `IsInitialized` within my handler as follows:

```
private void Radio_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsInitialized)
    {
        if(MyRadioButton.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            //SomeOtherElement is not initialized yet so it is null
            SomeOtherElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid having to use `if (this.IsInitialized)` in all my event handlers, as this is something I never had to do in WinForms.

So my question is, can I handle this a different way without having to add extra code to all my event handers?

Comment: You should take a look at the MVVM pattern that is used with WPF, that solves a lot of those problems.

Comment: @nvoigt: Yeah I have a WPF book at home that I really need to get around to reading. I believe it contains quite a bit about the MVVM pattern

Comment: You may like to see this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518231/wpf-getting-control-null-reference-during-initializecomponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I'm surprised that you aren't checking for `null` in your handlers anyway... checking for `IsInitialised` is just a slight variation on checking for `null`. Handling `null` values is just part of good programming and let's face it, it's not really adding a lot of code.

So to answer your question, I would say 'No, there is no way around checking for `null` (or `IsInitialised`) in your event handlers if you don't want `NulReferenceException`s to occur'.

However, when using the MVVM methodology, we don't use many events, preferring instead to use data binding and `ICommand` instances where possible. When we *do* need to use events, we generally use them in `Attached Properties`, but there you will still need to check for `null` values.

Comment: I don't see a need to check for null. The element should always be available and would much prefer the exception if it is null because it would be highly unexpected and should be addressed if it occurs. It seems I need to go away and investigate MVVM and consider how I can change my current approach to suit this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the event handler from the xaml and add it after `InitializeComponent();`

```
radioButton1.Checked+=Radio_Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Every element is created in that order it is in your XAML.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadioButton" ...>
<YourElement x:Name="SomeOtherElement" ...>
```

I assume in your XAML the RadioButton is placed before the other element you are referencing. On creation of an element in InitializeComponent all properties are set and also all events are fired. So SomeOtherElement does not exist in that moment.
The solution is quiet simple:

```
<YourElement x:Name="SomeOtherElement" ...>
<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadioButton"...>
```

Set SomeOtherElement before your RadioButtons.
If there are reasons to not switch the order of your elements in your XAML, then use the already mentioned null check:

```
if (SomeOtherElement != null)
{
    SomeOtherElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```